# Want to hide submenu on body click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to hide my submenu on body click. Currently it is not working like this, It only hides when clicked on the dropdown menu item. Here is the (https://deva.yuave.com) site where menu is.
I have tried to hide it on body click but it wont work. Plz help.. Here is the javascript code i am using for submenu..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--

window.onload=function() {
 subMenusO = getElementsByClassName(document,'ul','subMenus');
}
//-----------------------------------------------------------

function showSubMenu(elemId) {
 var dispStatus = (document.getElementById(elemId).style.display == 'block')? 'none' : 'block';
 //hide any visible submenus
 for(var i=0; i < subMenusO.length; i=i+1) {
     subMenusO[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
    //show/hide this menu id
    document.getElementById(elemId).style.display = dispStatus;
}
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------

function getElementsByClassName(oElm, strTagName, strClassName){
    var arrElements = (strTagName == "*" && oElm.all)? oElm.all : oElm.getElementsByTagName(strTagName);
    var arrReturnElements = new Array();
    strClassName = strClassName.replace(/\-/g, "\\-");
    var oRegExp = new RegExp("(^|\\s)" + strClassName + "(\\s|$)");
    var oElement;
    for(var i=0; i<arrElements.length; i++)
    {
        oElement = arrElements[i];
        if(oRegExp.test(oElement.className))
        {
            arrReturnElements.push(oElement);
        }
    }
    return (arrReturnElements)
}

//-->
</script>
```

Comment: where is your code of `click` listener on body?

Answer (score 2):

Something like this

```
$(document).click(function(e) {
    if (!$(e.target).is(".subMenus")){
        // hide submenus
        $('.subMenus').hide();
    }
});
```